# I can't make work oncomplete attributte

Tags: javascript, jsf, ajax4jsf

I'm tying to send some values after an action, this is my code:

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="button default" value="#{msg['cat.base.gdb.compte.valid']}"  action = "validar" oncomplete = "javascript:document.forms['form_0'].enviaDades.click();"  />
            <h:commandButton  type="submit" styleClass="button default" value="#{msg['cat.base.gdb.canviar.pais']}" action="canviPais" />

                    <a4j:commandLink styleClass="button default" id="enviaDades" onclick="javascript:actualitzarFormulariGDB(
                        '#{gdbBB.retorn.ideef}',
                        '#{gdbBB.retorn.ibanElectronic}',
                        '#{gdbBB.retorn.ibanPaper}',
                        '#{gdbBB.retorn.bic}');" value = "Això és una prova" />
```

the action seems to work perfectly and if i view the code page, the values have change, but oncomplete doesn't work, what it happens here?

ty.

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want to achieve using this code ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/a4j/commandButton.html) (oncomplete) :

> The client-side script method to be called after the DOM is updated

In your case, the DOM is not updated because you defined `action="validar"`, this will end with a page redirection instead. You are using a `a4j:commandButton` like a plain `h:commandButton`.

Comment: ty for answer, but i don't understand what you say...so what is the solution?

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao you are changing page and you want to execute the click of button `enviaDades`... you can't do both. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i do it soth like that..i don'e know if is the better solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript">//onload page become to work
            <!--
        var myvar=setInterval('prepararDadesRetorn()', 100);
        --> 
</script>



                <div class="right"> 
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" styleClass="button default" value="#{msg['cat.base.gdb.compte.valid']}"  action = "validar"/>                     
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" styleClass="button default" value="#{msg['cat.base.gdb.canviar.pais']}" action="canviPais" />
                    <h:commandButton  styleClass="button" value ="#{msg['cat.base.gdb.sortir']}"  style="display:inline;" onclick="javascript:window.close();"/>                    
                </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--    
                function prepararDadesRetorn() {
                    if('#{gdbBB.compteValid}'== 'true'){
                actualitzarFormulariGDB(
                    '#{gdbBB.retorn.ideef}',
                    '#{gdbBB.retorn.ibanElectronic}',
                    '#{gdbBB.retorn.ibanPaper}',
                    '#{gdbBB.retorn.bic}');             
                }
                }
            --> 
        </script>
```

if validation is correct I send the values to another form with the boolean condition..
ty.